# Regex issue, does not match entry with two columns

Tags: javascript, regex

I have got the following regex:

```
var match = str.match(/^[^,]*,[^,]*,.*$/mg);
```

To cover multi line entries like

```
1234,john smith, john
4321, john smith2, jack, william@ab.com
8765, daniel, smith, rocks
```

in the following demo link, when you paste the whole block of my example (all three lines), you can see three separate alert, each time alerting one line.

http://jsfiddle.net/TCMcp/2/

However, somehow when I try the same regex for the entries with two colums such as

```
3214, john
4321, jack
```

the regex does not match it and I get the whole block in one alert.

Any idea why?!

Comment: The regex matches in the second example with 2 columns

Comment: Can't you use `.split()` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's parse what your regex means :

```
/^[^,]*,[^,]*,.*$/mg

/^      Match from the start of the line

[^,]*   Anything but a comma, 0 or more occurrences

,       One comma

[^,]*   Anything but a comma, 0 or more occurrences

,       One comma

.*      Any character or symbol, 0 or more occurrences

$       Match the end of the line

/m      Multiline

g       Global
```

I'm not sure you really need the `mg` flags, but other than that, your problem is that your regex wants **two** commas. Basically you could condense it to :

```
/^[^,]*,.*$/mg
```

This will match lines that contain at least ONE comma.

Comment: using your regex in my example does not give me separate lines in separate alerts, you can see when you paste the first example block I provided you see three separate alert and each contains separate line

Comment: Ah, so maybe you DO need the `mg` flags after all.

Answer (score 1):

It will work if you put comma after second column because your regex match 2 commas.

You can fix regexi if you put second comma opional

```
/^[^,]*,[^,]*,?.*$/mg
```

And if you don't want to select whole text don't use `m` option to regex because it will match in multilne, in you case it match 3 columns where second colums have `\n` in the middle.

Comment: using your regex in my demo, I still get the second block example in one alert